# "drush up" is changing my selinux context

Tags: drush

Disclaimer: I have found a way to fix this problem short-term, but I'm curious if anyone can explain to me why it's happening, or if someone has found a better fix than what I'm doing.  If it exists already, Google has not revealed it to me.

Problem: (on a LAMP Server) When I use 'drush up' to update a module, or even core, the selinux context on the files is changed.  This is new behavior as far as I can tell. I have used 'drush up' to update core and modules in the past with no problems.  The changed selinux context results in a WSOD.  To fix this, I run restorecon -R on the drupal root, which results in a series of

> unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0

and then things work again, until the next 'drush up'.  If I have multiple modules to update I either update and restorecon repetitively, or take my chances and drush up -y, restorecon, and then hope for the best (not ideal obviously).

Drush 7 and Drush 8 both behave this way.  Oddly enough, when I 'drush dl' a module, it's brought in to the modules folder with the appropriate selinux context. Based on an ll -Z of files in the temp folder, I'm guessing (emphasis on guessing) that the files are getting moved from there rather than copied during an update, but I do not know enough about the inner workings of drush to be able to trouble shoot.  Any insight would be welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Adding the `--debug` option to the command will give you a verbose output of what it's doing which should help in finding what might be causing it.

Comment: This isn't really a Drupal or Drush question as it is about PHP and SELinux. A normal copy (using cp on the command line) would change the selinux context to the context of the parent directory. Either the context of the parent directory (sites/all/modules or similar) is wrong or copying using PHP bypasses the normal SELinux mechanisms. The normal problem with PHP and SELinux is connected to move_file_upload, but I don't think that is the case here as Drush is a command line tool. Using --debug as suggested is probably needed to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing to --debug.  While I don't have it all figured out yet, I think I've nailed down the basic problem.  Drush uses php's rename() function, which is a move and not a copy.  If rename isn't available for some reason, drush performs a copy followed by a delete.  By commenting out the portion that uses rename() and allowing the fallback copy/delete to happen, I get the functionality that I want/expect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Drush downloads the new files into /tmp, which creates them with the wrong SELinux context. Drush then renames (moves) the new files rather than copying them, which maintains the wrong context.

There's more info at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2412

```
diff --git a/includes/filesystem.inc b/includes/filesystem.inc
index 0d0f499..878b7d8 100644
--- a/includes/filesystem.inc
+++ b/includes/filesystem.inc
@@ -323,7 +323,7 @@ function drush_move_dir($src, $dest, $overwrite = FALSE) {
     return drush_set_error('DRUSH_DESTINATION_NOT_WRITABLE', dt('Destination directory !dest is not writable.', array('!dest' => dirname($dest))));
   }
   // Try rename. It will fail if $src and $dest are not in the same partition.
-  if (@drush_op('rename', $src, $dest)) {
+  if (FALSE && @drush_op('rename', $src, $dest)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   // Eventually it will create an empty file in $dest. See
```